# Simple JavaScript datepicker bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery datepicker, and I'm using this code ...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      //$("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

...at the header of my page. Meanwhile, with PHP, I want to call it an indefinite number of times.

But I can't use this function to place "datepicker" more that once if there is only one: `$("#datepicker").datepicker();` on the function.

How can I call this function an indefinite number of times?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960575/jquery-datepicker-multiple-instances

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer Steve.

Yes, it's a very close question. But i google previously and didn't find that.

Once again, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call a class ..

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

and you can call indefinite number of time ..just that all your input should have the class datepicker

example

```
<input name="test1" class="datepicker" />
<input name="test2" class="datepicker" />
.......
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer Bipen and Vision.

Yes, that was the answer i was looking for.

I already tested and works like a charm.

Once again, thanks for your help :) and sorry 'bout the noob question ^^

Answer (score 1):

IDs are meant to be unique.

Switch your `#datepicker` for `.datepicker` on your html and on your jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer Bigood.
bipen already posted the solution. 

but, once again, thanks for the help :)